# batch Script file for move files to the specific folder

Tags: batch, script

I have files like below:

```
L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)_10.jpg
L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)_11.jpg
DC_GEN_ENT_Billboard_10.jpg
DC_GEN_ENT_Billboard_11.jpg
```

And I having the folder names:

```
L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)
DC_GEN_ENT_Billboard.
```

I want to move the two files with the same name to the same folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Store L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical) and DC_GEN_ENT_Billboard into 2 variables and then use a condition on those to filter them.

Comment: Go the other way around, search files matching `foldername*` and move them.

Answer (score 0):

I used a root folder of C:\temp7, so you'll have to change that to wherever your folders are. This is a powershell script file. Open a notepad, paste this code, modify what you need, save as a .ps1 file and run it.

```
# Set source folder and destination folders
$sourceFolder = "C:\temp7"
$destinationFolder1 = "C:\temp7\L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)"
$destinationFolder2 = "C:\temp7\DC_GEN_ENT_Billboard"

# Find all files matching "L-Shaped" in and move into Lshaped folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter L-Shaped* | ForEach-Object { move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destinationFolder1 }

# Find all files matching "DC_GEN" in and move into DC_GEN folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter DC_GEN* | ForEach-Object { move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destinationFolder2 }
```